# Putting a dynamic hash in JQuery using rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, hash, jquery-ui-timepicker

I am newish to rails and new to JQuery.  I am using jquery.timepicker with rails and it takes hashes to block out certain time ranges in a given list of times (ie, between 8am and 6pm, 1pm-2pm is not available).  On a static page, the JQuery is written as so:

```
  <script>
    $('#someTextfieldPair .time').timepicker({
        'timeFormat': 'g:ia',
        'disableTimeRanges': [
          ['11:00am', '12:00pm'],
          ['3:00pm', '4:00pm']
        ]
     });
   </script>
```

Instead of static times, I'm trying to create the hashes based on the values @other_events.time_start and @other_events.time_end.  I've tried this, but I don't really know how to combine JQuery and rails.

```
 <script>
    $('#someTextfieldPair .time').timepicker({
        'timeFormat': 'g:ia',
        'disableTimeRanges': [
        <%= @other_events.each do |e| %>
          ['<%= e.time_start.strftime("%l:%M %P") %>', '<%= e.time_end.strftime("%l:%M %P") %>'],
          <%end %>
        ]
     });
   </script>
```

I am using this jquery.timepicker: http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to check https://github.com/gazay/gon gem, it's fantastic for rails: it generates a javascript object on top of page, so you can access your time ranges (per page!) in javascript like you would do with any variable.

Comment: Hey,  I've been trying to work with Gon and I asked another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29303678/placing-a-dynamic-rails-array-in-javascript-using-gon  ...I'd love you're help, if you have the chance , as I can only checkmark this question if gon eventually works.

Comment: Added a rather big answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

In `helper.rb`

```
def create_array(array_values)
   your logic......create your Hash or Array here
end
```

In your `js` file

```
<script>
    $('#someTextfieldPair .time').timepicker({
       'timeFormat': 'g:ia',
       'disableTimeRanges': $('#someTextfieldPair .time').after("#{escape_javascript create_array(@other_events)}")
   });
</script>
```