# Rails multi-dimensional array in JQuery Object Literal using Gon Gem

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-ui-timepicker

I am very new to JS & Jquery. I am building a scheduling app. I am storing appointments in a model called "Event". I am using a helper to build the multi-dimensional array  from values in columns called "event.time_start" and "event.time_end" for a given day that a user might make an appointment.   When a user picks a start_time and end_time from the dropdown menu, times that already have appointments will be grayed out/"disabled". I am using jquery.timepicker by http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/ with rails to blocks certain time values in a given array  of time pairs ( [8am, 6pm], [1pm, 2pm]).   
I am finding the "other" events on a given day (the ones that inform which times are taken) using the variable @other_events.

this is the helper that pairs the event.start_time and event.end_time
events_helper.erb

```
module EventsHelper

    def taken_times(other_events)
      other_events.map { |event| [event.time_start, event.time_end] }
      @taken_times = taken_times(other_events)
    end
end
```

I can get the array to work like this in the view:

```
<% taken_times(@other_events).each do |taken_time| %>
  <%= taken_time.first.strftime("%l:%M %P")%>
  <%= taken_time.last.strftime("%l:%M %P")%>,
 <% end %>
```

But I can't get it to work in the JS.  I am now trying to use the Gon Gem
What I need to out put to is this:

events/show.html.erb view

```
 <script>
     $('#jqueryExample .time').timepicker({
         'timeFormat': 'g:ia',
            'disableTimeRanges':   [
      // start dynamic array
    ['10:00am', '10:15am'],
    ['1:00pm', '2:15pm'],
    ['5:00pm', '5:15pm']
]
      //end dynamic array
     });
        $('#jqueryExample').datepair();
        </script>
```

so I've tried

application.html.erb

```
  <%= Gon::Base.render_data({}) %>
```

events_controller.erb

```
def show
 @event = Event.new
 @other_events = Event.where(date_id: params[:id])
 gon.taken_times = @taken_times
end
```

with the JS

```
 <script>
     $('#jqueryExample .time').timepicker({
         'timeFormat': 'g:ia',
            'disableTimeRanges':   [
      // start dynamic array
     gon.taken_times
      //end dynamic array
     });
        $('#jqueryExample').datepair();
        </script>
```

but this doesn't work.  it just kills the dropdown function of the textfields. I'd love to know what these comma separated objects like "'timeFormat': 'g:ia'," and "disableTimeRanges: [....]" are called so I can better search SO for javascript answers.  I am very new to JS & JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gon seems the right way to handle this but there are various errors in your code:

Where do you write `<%= Gon::Base.render_data({}) %>` ? It should be in the `<head>` tag, before any javascript code

Your `event_helper.rb` is wrong:

```
def taken_times(other_events)
  # Map returns a **copy**, if you don't assign it to anything, it's just lost
  other_events.map { |event| [event.time_start, event.time_end] }
  # This has **completely no sense**, this method will throw a stack level too deep error **every time you call it**, you should read a book about programming before trying to use rails
  @taken_times = taken_times(other_events)
end
```

If you want to use that, go for something like

```
def taken_times(other_events)
  other_events.map { |event| [event.time_start, event.time_end] }
end
```

The controller has the same problem of previous code

```
def show
 @event = Event.new
 @other_events = Event.where(date_id: params[:id])
 # @taken_times is not assigned, gon.taken_times will always be `null` in JS
 gon.taken_times = @taken_times
end
```

You should rewrite it like:

```
helper :taken_times
def show
 @event = Event.new
 @other_events = Event.where(date_id: params[:id])
 gon.taken_times = taken_times(@other_events)
end
```

And finally, you have a big syntax error in your javascript code, that's why everything disappear. Also you are using gon if it's something special. Gon just creates a plain **javascript object**, you can access it in javascript like you would do with anything else.

```
 <script>
     $('#jqueryExample .time').timepicker({
         'timeFormat': 'g:ia',
            // Here you have an opening square brackets, which is never closed
            // Also, there is no point in having a square brackets here or you'll have an array of array of array, while you want an array of array
            'disableTimeRanges':   [
      // start dynamic array
     gon.taken_times
      //end dynamic array
     });
        $('#jqueryExample').datepair();
        </script>
```

Which instead should be

```
 <script>
     $('#jqueryExample .time').timepicker({
         'timeFormat': 'g:ia',
            'disableTimeRanges': gon.taken_times
     });
        $('#jqueryExample').datepair();
        </script>
```

My main suggestion is, **read a Ruby book first**, not one with Ruby and Rails merged, you clearly need to improve your programming skills before doing anything. Start with something like [The Well Grounded Rubyist](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988657) and follow up with a good book about javascript (which I have yet to find, comments about it are well appreciated). Then go for [Rails 4 in Action](http://www.manning.com/bigg2/) and at this point you probably understand better what's going on.

[This is my recipe to become a good rails developer](http://www.quora.com/Whats-the-best-way-for-a-beginner-to-start-learning-Ruby-on-Rails/answer/Francesco-Belladonna)

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much for the reading,  I do have the sense that I'm learning things in an idiosyncratic order somethings.

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to Fire-Dragon-Dol.  I had to do a few more tweaks...I had to change the helper and add strftime to make it work. I also had to call the helper in a different way...In case anyone should like to see the working code:

```
module EventsHelper
def taken_times(other_events)
  other_events.map { |event| [event.time_start.strftime("%l:%M %P"), event.time_end.strftime("%l:%M %P")] }
end
end
```

events_controller.rb

```
include EventsHelper

def show
 @event = Event.new
 @other_events = Event.where(date_id: params[:id])
 gon.taken_times = taken_times(@other_events)
show
```

the view

```
  <script>
     $('#jqueryExample .time').timepicker({
         'timeFormat': 'g:ia',
    'disableTimeRanges':   
      // start dynamic array
    gon.taken_times
              // end dynamic array
 });
        $('#jqueryExample').datepair();
        </script>
```